# Print chunk of lines between matching patterns

Tags: awk, sed

I have a bunch of email archives which looks like the pattern below. I am trying to separate the emails which is separated by starting `From:` and ending with the pattern `From:` .

```
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Hello.
World
This is a test email.


From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: New Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Yet another test email
```

Using awk, `awk '/From/{p=1} p; /Date/{exit}' text.txt`. It gives:

```
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM
```

How can I possibly modify the `awk` command to get:

```
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Hello.
World
This is a test email.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to get only the first email out of your input file?

Comment: @MarcLambrichs Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not bothered about newline char then

```
$ awk '/^From:/{count++} count==1' infile 

$ awk -v mail_no=1 '/^From:/{count++}count==mail_no; count>mail_no{exit}' infile
```

Examples :

```
$ awk '/^From:/{count++} count==1' infile 
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Hello.
World
This is a test email.


$ awk '/^From:/{count++} count==2' infile 
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: New Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Yet another test email
```

To remove trailing newline char, I prefer to use `tac` like below

```
$ awk -v mail_no=1 '/^From:/{count++}count==mail_no;count>mail_no{exit} ' infile | tac | awk 'NF{found=1}found' | tac
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Hello.
World
This is a test email.
```

Input :

```
$ cat infile
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Hello.
World
This is a test email.


From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: New Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Yet another test email


From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: New Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Yet another test email
```

Comment: @veekram but this will output trailing newlines at the end

Comment: @veekram: I prefer `tac` command like this `awk -v mail_no=1 '/^From:/{count++} count==mail_no; count>mail_no{exit} ' infile | tac | awk 'NF{found=1}found' | tac`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I prefer to use `tac` for retrieved results, updated too

Answer (score 2):

For your current input it would be enough to apply the following GNU ***awk*** expression:

```
awk -v RS="\n\n\n+" 'NR==1{ print; exit }' file
```

The output:

```
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Hello.
World
This is a test email.
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine for the current input. But there are uneven numbers of carriage return. The correct matching separator  should be the next `From:` field. What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

This will extract all email from the data

```
String[] separated = data.split("From:");
separated[0];
separated[1]; ......

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> buchEmails = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
for(int i=0;i<seperated.length();i++){   
  Matcher matcher = p.matcher(seperated[i]);
    while(matcher.find()) {
      emails.add(matcher.group());
    }
   buchEmails.add(i,emails);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rajasekhar. But, what I am trying to achieve is chunk of raw email starting with From: and upto the next From: .

Comment: That was just sample text . There are 100's and 1000's of more such mails on single simple text field. Not a group exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If, like @veekram stated in one of the comments, the next "From:" is the separator, then something like:

```
awk '/From:/{p++} p>1{next}1' file
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a program designed to parse emails like `formail? For example to extract the first message:

```
<in.mbox formail -1 -f -ds
```

Output:

```
From: Bikram Suwal veekram@gmail.com
To: John Doe johndoe@gmail.com
Subject: Greetings
Date: 04/05/1990 10:30 PM

Hello.
World
This is a test email.
```